# What cx code must be used in the Programmable Search Engine JSON Api endpoint

Tags: google-api, google-search-api, google-image-search

According to [the rest api documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest) of the Programmable Search Engine documentation, the `cx` parameter must contain the Programmable Search Engine ID. The example uses `017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve` as example. When making our own search engine on https://cse.google.com/, it shows a hexadecimal search engine id, but when using that as the input for the `cx` parameter we get a bad request error. Using our API key with the example search engine code *does* work, which makes me believe that we are just entering something invalid into this field. I am unsure however where we are supposed to get the information for this field otherwise. What cx code must be used in the Programmable Search Engine JSON api endpoint?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

[image: Form data shown on Programmable Search with private information blanked out]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was likely an issue with Google's api itself not accepting the new format, as the documentation now mentions

> Note: The Search Engine ID (cx) can be of different format (e.g. 8ac1ab64606d234f1)